# Django Processing Bar between two requests

Tags: python, django, django-templates, celery, progress-bar

I have a calculation-intensive application, it takes inputs and processes about 10-15 formulas on the inputs including NPV, IRR-like calculations. I am implementing the calculations using template tags in django. Below are the code snippets :

[filters.py][1]

```
@register.filter
def **client_irr**(value,arg):
    fcf_list = []

    for i in arg:
        fcf_list.append(fcf(value,i))

    return round(npf.irr(fcf_list) * 100,2)
```

[inputs.html][2]

```
<div class="products-row">
                <div class="product-cell price">{{ i.parameter }}</div>
                <div class="product-cell price">{{ i.units }}</div>
                <div class="product-cell price">{{ i.values|**client_irr:**total_time}}</div>
</div>
```

**There are a lot of calculations like these!!**

I am implementing these calculations correctly? I am not sure, I find this way completely wrong!

The request for (/inputs) calculating the values takes about 20-22 seconds and the UI gets stuck, this creates a very user experience(UX).

So, I am looking for either a processing bar(which I am unable to get a good tutorial in Django) or a way to optimize these calculations.

Thank you, folks!! It means a lot! If you have any solutions please help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a celery task which will offload processing from endpoint and increase response time, when you start a celery task, celery will provide you with a task ID that you can use later on to track progress in real time. Check out https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states for storing custom states and progress for a celery task.

To track the processing progress in real time on the front end I would recommend using `django-channels` https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and open a websocket connection on your webpage to track the task that has started. This means that you can provide real time updates to your front end as the celery task progresses, rather than poll some REST api end point every X seconds to check the progress. Each time a calculation completes you can send a message from celery to the websocket channel connection that the user has connected to.

Each time the website receives a new websocket connection message it can contain progress percentage and you can have a progress bar update each time.